# Sum of all the possible real solutions of $(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)}}=2018$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Sum of all the possible real solutions of $(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)^{(x^2+4x+5)}}=2018$

**My try**

I knew that the answer is $-4$ (according to wolfram alpha) but i tried myself solving it by hand.

I tried making $x^2+4x+5=u$, solving for $u$, and then replacing $(x^2+4x+5)$. Then, the equation is $u^{u^u}=2018$, but after that i didn't find a way of solving this.

Any hints?

Comment: Cute.  To figure out what the sum of a bunch of numbers are you don't always have to know what the numbers themselves are.  Do you need to know what the solutions to $x^2 + 4x + 5 = u$ actually are in order to know what the sum of the solutions are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part 1:  show there is exactly one value of $u$ that solves $u^{u^u} = 2018$.

Part 2:  what is the sum of the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 + 4x +(5-u) = 0$?  Hint: the value of $u$ doesn't matter.

Comment: If OP means real solutions (which seems likely here), then the value of $u$ does matter: In order to have two real solutions, the quadratic polynomial in $x$ must have positive discriminant, or equivalently we must have $u > 1$. This follows from the facts, though, that (1) $u$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$ and (2) $1^{1^1} = 1$.

Comment: Oh, good point.  So there's a reason that the constant term in the polynomial is 5.

Comment: "The value of u doesn't matter".  I'd claim that is still true.  as the *exact* value *doesn't* matter.  But yes, it does matter that there is precisely one value and that it is greater than $1$ matters. but otherwise it doesn't matter.